# Azure Search Indexes are not being added/populated

Tags: azure, indexing, azure-search

I am trying to configure azure search in Sitecore. I followed [this article](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/configure-azure-search.html) to configure it.

But when I try to rebuild the indexes, the number of units processed is empty and the indexes are not reflecting in azure portal.

I have added the below connection string in ConnectionString.config file

```
<add name="cloud.search" connectionString="serviceUrl= https://XXXXsearchindex.search.windows.net;apiVersion=2017-11-11;apiKey=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
```

and have updated the web.config file like below

```
<add key="search:define" value="Azure" />
```

On rebuilding the indexes no units are processed
[image]

After making the configuration changes the site was taking long time to load, so I did an `iisreset`, but this shouldn't impact the indexes.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: I'm removing SXA tag as it is not SXA related. You have a general issue with probably connection to the Azure search service. Check Crawling.log to check details.

Answer (score 1):

Usually this is due to an invalid Azure Search connection string, check for a typo in the service endpoint or in the associated parameters.